# Assigning to 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') from incompatible type 'id'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `NSMutableArray` with `CGPoint`. When I try to add an object to my `CGPoint` variable I see this error:

> **Assigning to 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') from incompatible type 'id'**

Here's my code:

```
targetView.center = [arrayWithCoord objectAtIndex:1];
```

I tried the way Xcode suggests:

```
targetView.center = *((__bridge CGPoint *)([arrayWithCoord objectAtIndex:1]));
```

I also tried this:

```
targetView.center = ((NSValue *)arrayWithCoord[0]).CGPointValue;
```

In all cases I have `targetView.center = {0 , 0}`.

I am absolutely sure that the array isn't empty. See my `NSLog`s:

> 2016-08-17 00:41:40.760 newword[16497:819894] Element NSPoint: {154.5,
>   31}
>
> 2016-08-17 00:41:40.760 newword[16497:819894] Element NSPoint: {197.5,
>   31}
>
> 2016-08-17 00:41:40.760 newword[16497:819894] Element NSPoint: {240.5,
>   31}
>
> 2016-08-17 00:41:40.761 newword[16497:819894] target center result {0,
>   0}

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

it says Remove * from CGPoint

you are write

```
 CGPoint *
```

write

```
CGPoint
```

only

And used

```
NSValue *val = [arrayWithCoord objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint p = [val CGPointValue];
```

and then assign p to `targetView.center`

or make point by only one step

```
CGPoint p = [arrayWithCoord[0] CGPointValue];
```

Comment: I have the aim result:2016-08-17 09:36:03.682 newword[17057:841214]  P is   {154.5, 31}
2016-08-17 09:36:03.682 newword[17057:841214] target center result {0, 0}

Comment: i thing target center is not set, check with  target.center = CGPointMake(p.x, p.y) ;

Answer (score 2):

What is the `target` that you are trying to change?

The code for unwrapping the CGPoint from the NSValue in the array should work fine. You can test this by assigning it to a temporary variable, printing it, and then assigning it as the `center`.

Does setting the center to an arbitrary point like `@{3,5}` work, for instance?

Comment: I try move my button by click. targetView is a UIImages. [Screenshot](https://monosnap.com/file/4xR5yYVcRQK4YkAvD1YHruCctBpNUF.png)